# Can I add a framing block along a cable to meet stapling code requirements?

Tags: wiring

My question is about stapling wire. I came up short on a 12/2 romex run so I cannot staple it to the stud where the outlet box is. If I sister a short 2x4 to the stud, that will give me just enough slack to staple the romex. Would an inspector have a problem with this?

Comment: I hope you have 6" of wire in the box having to sister is a red flag that you were short on wire, but if you have 6" inside it should fly code just says stapled and the distance depending on if clamps are used or holes.

Comment: I have 6 inches in the box, no problem. I also wanted some slack past the staple. As things often go, the point became moot anyway:

Answer (score 3):

I am not very familiar with the term sister, but if it means you're adding a piece of stud to another stud to get closer to your NM for stapling. Then I would say no one would have a problem with that form a code standpoint. Just make sure you're in the center of the wall or at least 1 1/2" from the drywall.